# Send mosquitto messages to vernemq

Tags: mosquitto, mqtt-vernemq

I have installed VerneMQ and Mosquitto on two different servers and I am trying to send test messages from the Mosquitto server to see if they are received on the VerneMQ server.
For simplicity, let's call them:
VerneMQ - S1
Mosquitto - S2

On S1:

```
[user1t@s1 ]# netstat -tupln | grep 1883
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:1883         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13669/beam.smp
```

The S1, the config for VerneMQ should allow any connections:

```
[user1@s1 ]# cat /etc/vernemq/vernemq.conf | grep ano
## Allow anonymous users to connect, default is 'off'. !!NOTE!!
allow_anonymous = on

vernemq ping
Last login: Mon May 25 10:51:12 UTC 2020 on pts/2
pong
```

From S2

```
[user1@s2 ]# mosquitto_pub -h 10.0.0.1 -p 1883 -m "message1" -t "topic1" -d
Client mosq-wodJ1DYaw8yqeFMY95 sending CONNECT
Client mosq-wodJ1DYaw8yqeFMY95 received CONNACK (0)
Client mosq-wodJ1DYaw8yqeFMY95 sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m1, 'topic1', ... (8 bytes))
Client mosq-wodJ1DYaw8yqeFMY95 sending DISCONNECT
```

How can I check if the messages are received on the other machine. Running the vmq-admin session show does not provide any output

```
[user1@s1 ]# vmq-admin session show
Last login: Mon May 25 11:04:02 UTC 2020 on pts/2
```

Is there any location in the logs where I can I see the messages being processed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mosquitto_sub` command to see messages that have been published to the broker.

Run the following on S2

```
mosquitto_sub -h 10.0.0.1 -p 1883 -v -t "topic1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see how `mosquitto_pub` did a DISCONNECT? 
That's why the Verne session command doesn't show you a session.

If you want to forward messages from Verne to Mosquitto (or vice versa) you need to configure a bridge, either in Verne or in Mosquitto. And if you find it doesn't work, check your bridge config & make sure you have an understanding on how the topics are mapped.